# How to do right click recognition with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, right-click

```
$("div").on("rightclick", function() {
    alert("Right Click pressed");
});
```

How can I recognize if the right click is pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("div").contextmenu(function() {
    alert("Right click pressed");
});
```

Comment: Better keep using `on`: `$("div").on("contextmenu", function() {...})`

Comment: Thanks! The code works.